# Flutter - How to change TextFormField fillColor according Validation result

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, input, textformfield

I want to change `TextFormField` `fillColor` according to result of validation. Same as below:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code directly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String text = '';
  bool validate = false;
  Color green = Colors.green.shade50;
  Color red = Colors.red.shade50;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (value) {
                  validate = false;
                  if (value.toString().isEmpty ||
                      !value.toString().contains('@')) {
                    return 'Enter valid Email';
                  } else {
                    validate = true;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: validate ? green : red,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.alternate_email_outlined,
                    color: validate ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: validate
                      ? const Icon(
                          Icons.check_outlined,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.close_outlined,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                  errorBorder: borderStyleFalse,
                  enabledBorder: validate ? borderStyleTrue : borderStyleFalse,
                  focusedBorder: validate ? borderStyleTrue : borderStyleFalse,
                  focusedErrorBorder: borderStyleFalse,
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    text = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  formKey.currentState!.validate();
                },
                child: const Text('call'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  OutlineInputBorder borderStyleTrue = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
  );
  OutlineInputBorder borderStyleFalse = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
  );
}
```

and this the result

when you open the screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaiti.jpg)

when you write and wrong message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfiFG.jpg)

when you write email right [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rpIF.jpg)

Comment: ur welcome
see the code and the images again 
i add some changes (i edit the photos)

Answer (score 1):

use a global bool variable that is changed depending on validation result

```
bool correct = null
.
.
.
TextFormField(
fillColor: correct ? Colors.green : correct! ? Colors.red : Colors.white //extra check for null if no value yet
validate:(value) {
     if (value){
        correct = true
     }
     else {
      correct = false
       }
}
)
```

Comment: For ui update I must to write if (value){ setState(()=>correct = true); } right? it throws error while setState called in validator block "setstate() or markneedsbuild() called during build"

Comment: yes setstate is needed, sorry I wrote it on my phone so I missed a few stuff, feel free to edit the answer to make it 100% correct before checking it if it's satisfactory